# Is it possible to have separate domain alias & redirection depending on subdirectory?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, domain-aliasing

I need to set up the aliasing/redirection of a domain name depending on whether its in a subdirectory or not.

`newdomain.com` is an alias for `parent.com/newdomain`. This is set up as an alias in the hosting control panel and is working.

I need the url to appear differently depending on the file, e.g

- Files in `newdomain.com` should appear in the location bar as
  `parent.com/newdomain/filename.php`
- Sub-directories in `newdomain.com` should appear in the location bar
  as `newdomain.com/subdir/filename.php`

I can use htaccess to control redirection, but I haven't found a way for it to control aliasing. 
Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is based on the assumption that `newdomain.com` and `parent.com` are being served from same Apache process.

Put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory of `newdomain.com`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?newdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/+subdir/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://parent.com/newdomain%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NC]
```

Once you verify that it's working then change `R=302` to `R=301`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @anubhava. At the moment newdomain.com is only an alias and doesn't have hosting set up for it. Is setting up hosting the only way I'll be able to have different aliases in the location bar?

Comment: In that I believe you don't need to setup hosting for `newdomain.com`. Just enable `mod_rewrite`, `.htaccess` and put above code in the `$DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory of `parent.com`.

Comment: When you said above to "Put .htaccess in the root dir of newdomain.com " I thought you meant I needed hosting - I assume you meant to say parent.com? I had tried htaccess in parent.com before and it didn't work, but I'll try yours. Thanks